# The html content appears before the loading starts

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, loading

I copied some JavaScript code just to wait until everything is loaded and then show the content. The thing is that sometimes I see a flash of content before the loader starts and this is not what a want.

Here I did a codepen in order to simplify things.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MI5Studio/pen/pKXBjm)

```
$(document).foundation();


(function($) {



$WIN = $(window);

// Add the User Agent to the <html>
// will be used for IE10 detection (Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0))
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);


   /* Preloader
    * -------------------------------------------------- */
var clPreloader = function() {
    
    $("html").addClass('cl-preload');

    $WIN.on('load', function() {

        //force page scroll position to top at page refresh
        // $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'normal');

        // will first fade out the loading animation 
        $("#loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
            $("#preloader").delay(300).fadeOut("slow");
        }); 
        
        // for hero content animations 
        $("html").removeClass('cl-preload');
        $("html").addClass('cl-loaded');
    
    });
};

/* Initialize
* ------------------------------------------------------ */
(function ssInit() {
    
    clPreloader();
   
    
})();
    
    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That is because JS loads after the DOM has first rendered. What you need to do is apply a class to the `body` element that makes it `display:none` and then remove that class when the page has loaded and your javascript has run. CSS renders before JS.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if I hide the elements in the body it will no show the preloader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment...

> That is because JS loads after the DOM has first rendered. What you need to do is apply a class to the body element that makes it display:none and then remove that class when the page has loaded and your javascript has run. CSS renders before JS.

If you can't do it on the body, wrap your content in a `div` and leave the loader out of the div, like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div id="content" class="hidden">/* website content here*/</div>
</body>
```

And like I said before, just remove the hidden class when you are ready and loaded.

Comment: I have aded some css to the codepen. In the codepen looks like it works but not when I upload to the server

Comment: @user3430043 first off, that is a dope loading gif. Second, are the IDs and classes exactly the same. Maybe your server is caching the old files? To refresh and clear you cache press cmd + shift + R. I'm not sure what it is on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, javascript loads after the DOM has.
You should give your body an identifier (like an ID): `<body id="mySite">`

Then you can set the CSS of that ID to be hidden: `#mySite: display:none;` in your CSS.
This will hide anything from loading when the site originally loads.

Then once your javascript has loaded, you can undo that rule.
Something like `document.getElementById("mySite").style.display = "block";` could work.

If the `display` rules isn't working, try `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;`, which should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way:

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KejOXO/)

I've wrapped everything after preloader in a body and i've put an id on it.

```
<body id='bdy'>
```

Then, after loading your preloader you set body's visibility to visible again.

```
clPreloader();
document.getElementById('bdy').style="display:block";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

instead of

```
$WIN.on('load', function() {
```